# Graphhopper Alternative Routes Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper

Is there a way to get more alternative routes in Graphhopper androd, I seem to be getting 2/3 routes at most in a calculation.I have a map containing information about CCTV camera locations, and I am trying to find the route that has maximum number of cameras.

I cannot seem to find any properties to change to get more alternative routes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Parameters.AltRoute.MAX_PATH` should increase this count but low quality paths are excluded. To force lower quality paths you need to adjust [some other parameters](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/alternative-routes/424/11?u=karussell), see also the discussion there for more information and keep in mind that those parameters are likely to change in future versions.